# .net cassette generate AMD

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, cassette

It would seem like cassette already does what I'd need and then some for most of what I want to do, but had one additional question...

Is there a way to setup bundle dependencies? I'd like to use it like AMD, even if it gets pre-compiled.

such that I can define a resource for x page, and say it needs this bundle, that bundle and those bundles dependencies and have it build out appropriate minified bundles.

I saw a twitter post about cassette supporting requirejs, as well as the nuget package for requirejs, but am really finding no documentation other than how to use requirejs as is, defining modules manually and having cassette serve that up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same questions as you have, and while I don't see much, I do see a thread on github where there is some discussion:
https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette/issues/248

In there is a link to a test project where he was working on the RequireJS integration: https://github.com/andrewdavey/reference-application/tree/master/App

However, his last comments in that thread indicate that while the code was functional it never made it past the experimental phase. You might not want to use this in a production environment.